# CKEdtior less than sign (<) is not shown after saving

Tags: ckeditor, symbols

I am using a Redmine installation with the CKEditor plugin. We started to document our work in the wiki. One problem is that some commands are not shown correctly after saving.

For example, I write:

```
mysql -u root -p bitnami_redmine < backup.sql
```

but after saving the page, the less-than sign and everything after it is gone:

```
mysql -u root -p bitnami_redmine
```

What can I do to correct this behavior?